# How to update laravel date without updating time

Tags: laravel

Im trying to update the `updated_at` in laravel `"2019-01-07 20:29:13"` to `"2019-15-18 20:29:13"`, but the problem is the time keeps updating also to `"2019-15-18 00:00:00"`. How to update `updated_at` without touching the time ?

Comment: `updated_at` is provided by laravel elquent with **dateTime** format, if you want to date then add a another field on this table with `date` format, or format updated_at to `d-m-y` while want to view

Comment: `2019-15-18 20:29:13` is not valid date.

Comment: @Tpojka exactly !!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help guyz, I solve my problem by retrieving the date of old data and store the time in $oldTime variable, then combine with my  $new_date." ".$oldTime and inserted it to updated_at column by temporary save([timestamps' =>false]) when saving the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of updating `updated_at` column you can add another column for this purpose and take it as `date` type only (recommended). But if you are not allowed to do this then you can try:

1. Get the existing `date` and hold it in a variable and break it to get date and time separately or you can extract the time only.
2. Combine your `date` with this `time` and make it datetime `'y-m-d H:i:s'` using `date()` and `strtotime()` functions.
3. Update the `updated_at` column with this new datetime value.

Comment: Thanks you, yes i use ur solution and you give me an idea to  solve my problem . I retrieve  the date of old data and store the time in $oldTime variable, then combine with my  $new_date." ".$oldTime and inserted it to updated_at column by temporary save([timestamps' =>false]) when saving the data.

Comment: Enjoy the coding :)